# Streaming log files to remote client

Tags: java, linux, logging, stream, syslog

I have a Java app running on a remote server (debian linux). The app logs runtime informations to files.

Once in a while, the support needs to analyze the logs using a client tool (not running on the server, but on the support's desktop). The tool then needs remote access to

1. old log files on the server
2. the current log file (growing in real time)

I'm searching a good (=standard, flexible, secure, well debugged etc) way to stream these past and present log messages to my client tool.

How would go about doing this?

Does a library exist, which provides this service?

Can syslog be adapted to do this?

Edit: For privacy reasons, the log files should be stored on the remote server only and not generally sent to a central logging service.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)'s capability as a publisher of log files to a remote server via TCP? Log4j is a standard Java logging tool (well-known/well-documented) and setting up the remote connectivity is pretty straightforward.

I've used this in the past to transmit across networks and collate log files from multiple machines in one common searchable directory structure (very useful in grid environments when you don't know where your processes could be running)

See [this page](http://nilshb.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/apache-log4j-as-log-server/) for more details.

Comment: I suspect they want to be able to see files changing on another machine on an ad hoc basis. with out using CDFS or NFS :|

Comment: That is what this provides. TCP transmission of log entries to a remote process

Comment: Interesting, so I can say I want the last weeks logs and the current logs to come to my PC only as required. i.e. when I know I have an issue.  You wouldn't want to be sending the logs to every PC which might want to see the logs.

Comment: If this is not possible you could stream the logs to a network share which is accessible to all the PCs.

Comment: Using this, you'd get the logs appearing in real time on your central server. It's not a broadcast/multicast mechansim (although you can do that via a Datagram appender)

Comment: Pulling down old files as required is a bad idea in any case.  It is better to have them available before you need them.

Comment: For privacy reasons, the log files should be stored on the server only and not generally sent to a central logging server.

Comment: What about logging to a database, and reading that database from the tool? Can this be configured to get notified of new log messages?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is likely to setup samba on the Linux box so you can access the logs remotely as they are updated without having to copy them.

---

You could use rsync.  This allows you to securely copy changes to files between machines. i.e. an appending file would only copy the changes since the last rsync.  Note: you have to run it repeatedly to keep seeing updates.

If the tools could be modified to support SSH e.g. via VFS, then you could access the remote files as if they were local.